# Azure Web App Goes Down

Tags: azure-web-app-service, cpu-usage

I recently started a web app for my company and made it through azure. It was originally on WordPress. I was alerted that the site was down. I then logged into azure and once i clicked the URL through the new azure portal, the site began working again. Does anyone have any idea why/how this could have happened. I cant really find any information online about it.

It turns out our CPU usage went up to 100% around 7AM randomly. What could have caused this, and does the website come back on after this happens?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have configured the Always on option.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/windows-azure-staging-publishing-support-for-web-sites-monitoring-improvements-hyper-v-recovery-manager-ga-and-pci-compliance

This blog explains how to do it.